# OnclickListener on RecylerView and getting the Id of clicked Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I need to set onClickListener on RecyclerView which gets the Json Id of an Item Clicked and redirects to the fragment which displays the details of the product based on that Json ID.  How Can I implement this in adapter? I am stuck here. I was able to set onClickListener but I couldn't get the Json ID.

This is my Adapter.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.MainActivity;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.R;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.apiHandlers.model.Ad;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dell on 7/3/2017.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Ad> ads;
    private Context context;



    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Ad> ads, Context context){
        this.ads=ads;
        this.context=context;

    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_ads, parent,false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(ads.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.details.setText("Rs. " +ads.get(position).getPrice().toString()+ "/-");
//        Glide.with(context).load(ads.get(position).getPhoto1()).into(holder.thumbnail);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ads.size();
    }




    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView name, details;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            thumbnail=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            details=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Recycler View" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.dell.retroexample;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.dell.retroexample.apiHandlers.adapter.RecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.apiHandlers.model.Ad;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.apiHandlers.rest.ApiInterface;
import com.example.dell.retroexample.apiHandlers.rest.ApiClient;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter=null;
    private List<Ad> ads;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.ads_recycler_view);
                // calculating the number of columns
        int columns=2;
        DisplayMetrics lDisplayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        double widthPixels = lDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.e("Width", String.valueOf(widthPixels));
        columns=(int)widthPixels/dpToPx(170);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,  columns);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        apiInterface=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call <List<Ad>> call=apiInterface.getads();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Ad>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Ad>> call, Response<List<Ad>> response) {
                ads=response.body();
                adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(ads, MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Ad>> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });




    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(ads.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.details.setText("Rs. " +ads.get(position).getPrice().toString()+ "/-");        Glide.with(context).load(ads.get(position).getPhoto1()).into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id=ads.get(position).getId();
                //You can call detail fragment here
            }
        });
    }
```

> Note: Remove onclick listener from ViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

try this using below class you can get recyclerview onclick listener and longclick listneeers

create a **RecyclerItemClickListener** class

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}


@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
}
```

**now add lister to recyclerview like this**

```
        indexRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(MainActivity.this, indexRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                   /// perform your action here


                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            })
    );
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getLayoutPosition();
                    String id=ads.get(position).getId();
                    // call fragment
                }
}
```

**Add this in ViewHolder Constructor.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Ad ad = ads.get(RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition());` in your OnCkick method to retrieve the current object. Then use Interface to pass the value to the fragment.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Recycler View" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Ad ad = ads.get(RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition());
               //use interface to pass ad to the fragment....
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter class should be like below.

You have to remove `onClickListener` from `ViewHolder` class. and set click in `onBindViewHolder` Method.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Ad> ads;
    private Context context;



    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Ad> ads, Context context){
        this.ads=ads;
        this.context=context;

    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_ads, parent,false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(ads.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.details.setText("Rs. " +ads.get(position).getPrice().toString()+ "/-");
//        Glide.with(context).load(ads.get(position).getPhoto1()).into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Write your code here to send data to fragment*/
                Ad ad = ads.get(position);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ads.size();
    }




    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView name, details;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            thumbnail=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            details=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            linearLayout=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); // its your main layout
        }



    }
}
```